# Intercept **Outgoing** HTTP(S) Traffic

Tags: http, proxy, wireshark, traffic, charles-proxy

With Tools like Charles or Telerik's Fiddler you can set up your own proxy server on your home PC, intercepting in- and outgoing traffic on a more High-Level (but easier to read) view than e.g. wireshark.
Is there a way to actually analyze and or intercept the real outgoing traffic without needing to use a proxy? Just by somehow catching all the Traffic before it gets sent out to the wire? It doesn't need to be on bit layer (the plain HTTP requests would be just fine ;) )

Regards

Comment: For intercepting https traffic without a proxy you need to capture the data before it is getting encrypted in the process that sends it. The main problem is that there are several SSL/TLS libraries that can be used by programs. For intercepting traffic you need to write a different hook to get the decrypted data. As such tools use techniques of a debugger to modify running processes such tools are often called https debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're mentioning about iOS app, you can do it by [Atlantis Framework](https://docs.proxyman.io/atlantis/atlantis-for-ios) + [Proxyman](https://proxyman.io) app.

Instead of proxying your traffic to a proxy server, like Charles, Fiddler does, Atlantis will capture your traffic on-the-wire (by using the Method Swizzling technique) and broadcast it to the Proxyman app for previewing.